# TFileStream and TMemoryStream typing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Why can't I do this?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create('file', fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    TMemoryStream(FS).SaveToFile('tempfile');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FS);
  end;
end;
```

I have a method with a `AStream: TStream` parameter and calling it with both types of stream.  I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this because `TFileStream` is not a descendent of `TMemoryStream`.

Indeed, the fact that you needed to cast to make the compiler happy should have been sufficient warning that your code is wrong. All your cast does is tell the compiler to shut up and that you know better. In this case you don't. You are lying to the compiler and it will exact revenge in due course.

What you are really looking for is [`TFile.Copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.Copy). This is significantly better than using streams to manually perform a file copy. The point being that `TFile.Copy` goes via the operating system and so is able to copy efficiently, retain file metadata, copy alternate file streams, and so on.

Well, at least that is true on Windows. The other operating systems that Delphi supports do not have an equivalent to the Win32 `CopyFile` API and so `TFile.Copy` does indeed implement this with streams. However, it is still preferable to let the runtime library wrap up these details for you.

Comment: I now understand it. I have very difficult method structure and now I must clear it. Thank you.